# Dereferencing Issue with 2D Arrays

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, multidimensional-array, dereference

Trying to understand C pointers w/2D arrays. Looking at some old notes from back when I was a student.

**The code:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define size 100

int main(){
    float x[size][size],a[size],b[size],sum=0,result;
    int i,j,M,N;
    float *xPtr;
    xPtr=&x[0][0];
    
    printf("Please enter the number of students: ");
    scanf_s("%d",&M);
    printf("Please enter the number of quizzes: ");
    scanf_s("%d",&N);
    printf("\n");

    for(i=0;i<M;i++){
        for(j=0;j<N;j++){
          printf("Enter the grade for student # %d in quiz # %d: ",i,j);
          scanf_s("%f",&x[i][j]);
        }
    }

    printf("\n\t");
    for(j=0;j<N;j++){
        printf("\t\tquiz # %d",j);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(i=0;i<M;i++){
        printf("student # %d",i);
        for(j=0;j<N;j++){
            printf("\t\t%.2f\t",x[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    for(i=0;i<M*N;i++){
        printf("\nx[%d][%d]=%0.2f\n",i/N,i%N,*(xPtr+i));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**The console output (# of students=3, # of quizzes=2): [image: output_1]**

The alternative given to avoid this problem was to change the dereferencing portion of the code
from

```
for(i=0;i<M*N;i++){
        printf("\nx[%d][%d]=%0.2f\n",i/N,i%N,*(xPtr+i));
    }
```

to

```
for(i=0;i<M;i++){
        for(j=0;j<N;j++){
            printf("\nx[%d][%d]=%.2f\n",i,j,*((xPtr+i*size)+j));
        }
    }
```

**The console output of this approach is successful (# of students=3, # of quizzes=2): [image: output_2]**

The explanation given as to why the first dereferencing approach fails is the following:

> QUESTION: Why are the elements `x[1][0],x[1][1],x[2][0],x[2][1]` coming out to be `0.00`?

> ANSWER: Because there is a mismatch between `size=100` and the actual # of rows and columns. This problem does not arise with 1D arrays where, if the actual # of elements in the 1D array is less than size, it does not matter since the elements after the actual number of elements are zero and do not count.

**MY QUESTION:**

1. I don't understand the explanation given (why is there a mismatch and why does the problem not arise w/1 arrays?). If the pointer is pointing to the first element of the array (ie. `xPtr=&x[0][0];`) then can't we increment by one each time (ie. `xPtr+i`) and step element by element since a 2D array is stored sequentially as a a 1D array with each row one after another?
2. I don't understand the implementation of dereferencing in the successful approach, specifically, what is the function of including `size` in the dereference `(*((xPtr+i*size)+j))`, my intuition would have been to do something like `*(*(xPtr+i)+j)` with the two nested dereference operators. Would that work? How was he able to get away with using only one here? I guess he is using size to shift forward by the row size, but I'm not entirely sure how it all works together...

Comment: OT:  the posted code does not cleanly compile!  When compling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.

Comment: strongly suggest using the 'Variable Length Array' feature of C.  Specifically 1 remove all references to `size`.  2) read the dimensions of the 2d array first, then declare the array:  `float x[M][N];`  Then the array will never be smaller (nor larger) than the values in 'M' and in 'N' and there will be no unused array positions that need to be accounted for and the user cannot declare an array those 'size' is greater than what gets declared in the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you already have enough information to understand that concept. You know that 2D array are really stored in linear address space.

The mismatch is caused by the fact that you allocated more space in a table row than you used. When you try to get the values you should omit that unused space. That's why the fix multiplies the current row by the row size, to jump to the first element of the row you are aiming to read from.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 4

void main()
{
    char buf[SIZE][SIZE];
    int n = 2;

    printf("Normal addresses:\r\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
        {
            printf("%p\t", &buf[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\r\n");
    }
    char* start = &buf[0][0];

    printf("Broken way:\n\r");
    for(int i = 0; i < n*n; i++)
    {
        printf("%p\t", start + i);  
        if((i+1)%n == 0)
        {
            printf("\r\n");
        }
    }
    printf("Fixed way:\n\r");
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            printf("%p\t", start + (i*SIZE)+j);  
        }
        printf("\r\n");
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Normal addresses:
0x7ffe128dd2e0  0x7ffe128dd2e1  0x7ffe128dd2e2  0x7ffe128dd2e3
0x7ffe128dd2e4  0x7ffe128dd2e5  0x7ffe128dd2e6  0x7ffe128dd2e7
0x7ffe128dd2e8  0x7ffe128dd2e9  0x7ffe128dd2ea  0x7ffe128dd2eb
0x7ffe128dd2ec  0x7ffe128dd2ed  0x7ffe128dd2ee  0x7ffe128dd2ef
Broken way:
0x7ffe128dd2e0  0x7ffe128dd2e1
0x7ffe128dd2e2  0x7ffe128dd2e3
Fixed way:
0x7ffe128dd2e0  0x7ffe128dd2e1
0x7ffe128dd2e4  0x7ffe128dd2e5
```

Regarding the second question, you can get the elements via `*(*(xPtr+i)+j)`, but you have to give a compiler a hint how long the rows are. Please consider following example, compiler can find that information in pointer type.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 4

int main()
{
    char buf[SIZE][SIZE];
    int n = 2;

    printf("Normal addresses:\r\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
        {
            printf("%p\t", &buf[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\r\n");
    }
    char (*start)[SIZE] = &buf[0];
    printf("Read:\n\r");
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            printf("%p\t", (*(start+i)+j));  
        }
        printf("\r\n");
    }

}
```

Comment: Ok, it seems to make sense to me why this works: `*((xPtr+i*size)+j)`. However, I am now confused as to why we need to use TWO dereference operators to access the values stored at the memory addresses when employing this approach: `*(*(xPtr+i)+j)` when the preceding example only requires ONE? It seems to me if we use two than the inner will dereference first and we will add the `+j` to the value at `*(xPtr+i)` ? Based on the success of the first approach I would expect that we should implement the second with only one dereference operator as such: `*((xPtr+i)+j)`.

Comment: When applied to an array, the index operator adds the argument to a pointer that points to first element of that array and then dereferences that pointer. In `&buf[0][0]` you effectively execute two dereferences and then use the `&` to get the result's address. In the second example the start is assigned to `&buf[0]` -> only one dereference. The start points to the address of a char[SIZE] not single char. `*(start+i)` is necessary for result to point to single elements not whole rows.

Comment: Ah, my confusion was in the fact that the pointer to an array (`char (*start)[SIZE] = &buf[0];`) is different than the pointer to the 0th element of the array (`xPtr=&x[0][0];`); The former which, I believe, dereferences to an address and the later to a value.